# Configuring DNS to resolve root remotely and subdomain locally

Tags: dns

Let's say I own the domain `example.com`, and have a website hosted on an external server at `http://example.com`, which is also accessible from `http://www.example.com`.

I want to run my local OwnCloud instance at `http://cloud.example.com`, which should be accessible both locally and remotely. To make this accessible via LAN in my own network, I set up a local BIND server which resolves `cloud.example.com` to the local IP address of the server. However, since this is the only server, browsing to `http://example.com` resolves to the same machine and not to the remote website.

How could I set up my BIND server to do the following?

- Accessing `cloud.example.com` from the LAN should resolve to a local IP
- Accessing `cloud.example.com` through the Internet should work (will use dynamic DNS for this)
- Browsing to `http://example.com` or `http://www.example.com` from LAN or Internet should display the externally hosted website

I am fairly new to DNS implementations so happy to RTFM if needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you need the views functionality in BIND. as you are happy, [here](https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-00851/0/Understanding-views-in-BIND-9-by-example.html) is the isc knowledge base article with examples:

```
# named.example02.conf

acl trusted { 192.168.7.0/24; localhost; };
acl guest   { 192.168.8.0/24; };

view trusted {
    match-clients { trusted; };

    allow-recursion { any; };

    zone "myzone.example" {
        type master;
        file "trusted/db.myzone.example";
    };
    zone "7.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "trusted/db.192.168.7";
    };
};

view guest {
    match-clients { guest; };

    allow-recursion { any; };

    zone "myzone.example" {
        type master;
        file "guest/db.myzone.example";
    };
};
```

as you can see above `myzone.example` will be readed from `trusted/db.myzone.example` for `192.168.7.0/24` and `localhost`, but for `192.168.8.0/24` zone will be readed from another file.

Comment: I would suggest summarizing the link in your answer. This makes your answer more helpful when looking at it, but also keeps the information on super user in the (unlikely) event the remote site goes down. :)

Comment: suggest accepted, summarize done.

Comment: This is not really helpful because I don't have different subnets in my LAN and I'm not exposing the local DNS server to the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by copying the same A records on my remote DNS to my local DNS server. Not 100% ideal since there's some duplication, but it's very likely that those records will never change.